# Show that $7 |(n^6 + 6)$ if $7 ∤ n$, $∀ n ∈ ℤ$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, divisibility, factoring

> Show that $7 |(n^6 + 6)$ if $7 ∤ n$, $∀ n ∈ ℤ$

I need to prove this by the little Fermat's theorem.

**My attempt**

$n^6 \equiv -6 \pmod 7$

To show $7  ∤ n$ I need to show that $N$ is not congruent to $0$ mod $7$.

as $-6 \equiv 1\pmod 7$

$n^6 \equiv 1\pmod7$

But now, How can I show $N$ is not congruent to $0$ mod $7$ ?

Comment: The if statement allows you to assume that $n$ is not congruent to zero - you are only asked to show that the statement is true for the other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) we know that:
**Remark**: For every $n$, with $7 \nmid n$ we have : 
$ \ \ \ \ \ n^6 \overset{7}{\equiv} 1 \ \ .$

---

$$ 
n^6 \overset{7}{\equiv} 1 
\Longrightarrow 
n^6 -1 \overset{7}{\equiv} 0 
\Longrightarrow 
n^6 -1 + 7 \overset{7}{\equiv} 0 
\Longrightarrow 
n^6 + 6 \overset{7}{\equiv} 0 
. 
$$

Comment: @hjx ; In these type of problems; (this question and your previous question in last night) 
[Fermat's little theorem][1]
and 
[Euler's theorem][2] 
may be help a lot.
  [1]: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem
  [2]: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem

Comment: I got it, thanks, I only had misunderstand the if statement, But Could I also prove this by contradiction ?

Comment: @hjx ; I myself; do not have any idea how to prove this statement by contradiction.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the amazing answer.

Answer (score 4):

Because $n^6+6=n^6-1+7$ and  $n^6-1$ divisible by $7$.

$$n^6-1=(n-1)(n+1)(n^2-n+1)(n^2+n+1)$$
and now easy to check $n\equiv\pm1,\pm2\pm3(\mod7)$.

Comment: Nice solution without using Fermat's little theorem!

Comment: @Hamsteriffic By Fermat's little theorem it's obvious of course.